# VirtualBox returning error when making a VM on MacOS Big Sur

Tags: macos, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, iso-image

I am trying to make a VM in VirtualBox on my 16 inch Intel MacBook Pro. I go through the setup of making the virtual machine (defining the OS, allocating RAM and Storage, etc.). Once that is all complete I go to launch it so that I can direct it to the ISO of Ubuntu 20.04.2 Server that I want to run and it instantly exits before I can select the ISO. Here is the error code and I have tried some fixes online but to no avail. Any help?

[image: Error Message from VirtualBox]

[image: MacBook Pro SPECS]

Comment: There were some hoops to jump through on Big Sur - see https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=39&t=98763&start=15 to see it unfold. I don't know if these were fully resolved later, so you may have some reading to do…

Comment: Alternatively, try VMWare Fusion - the home user version is now freeware.

Comment: @Tetsujin thank you for your help I'll go through the forum link you sent and thank you for your recommendation of VMWare Fusion I like it I just wish I could get VirtualBox working as I'm more accustomed to it.